# Uniquely identify external storage

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, hardware

Using C++ and the Win32 API, I have to uniquely identify an external HDD. That is, I have to retrieve some sort of ID number, which I can later use to see if the same HDD is connected to the computer.

Comment: Define unique in this context.

Comment: Mounted Windows Storage Volumes have a unique GUID.  See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/ifs/storage-volumes

Comment: How secure does it need to be? Could you just place a hidden file as a marker?

Comment: Is the requirement for you to recognize the drive, or do you expect someone to try to fake it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That assumes you have write access. And it is highly intrusive. And more vulnerable than anything else. It's the kind of crap I would expect from Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to retrieve the HDD serial number. You could use WMI to retrieve this, here's a PowerShell command to do this:

> Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMedia | select SerialNumber

Note that the returned serial number may be returned in a mangled or encoded form.

A sample how to code this in C++ can be seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx). Basically you need to connect to the IWbemServices COM root\cimv2 namespace, study the documentation for details.